# Two sites using SSL running on one IP

Tags: ssl, apache2

I am having some trouble getting my apache server to deliver the correct IP address when users browse to the second domain in my config. Here is an example of what my config currently looks like. This config will give the following error to the clients "Servers certificate does not match the URL.". Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    Redirect / https://www.domain1.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName www.domain1.com
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /location/ofcerts/www_domain1_com.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /domain1/www_domain1_com.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /location/ofcerts/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
            SSLCertificateChainFIle /location/ofcerts/domain1.ca-bundle
            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
            SSLHonorCipherOrder on
            SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
        <Location />
            SetEnv no-gzip
        </Location>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/sub>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.domain2.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /location/of/domain2certs/www_domain2_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /domain2/www_domain2_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /location/of/domain2certs/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFIle /location/of/domain2certs/domain2.ca-bundle
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on


        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
        <Directory /var/www/domain2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: One of the limitations of `https` is that it allows only one URL per IP address.

Comment: When a request hits the server the host-header is encrypted so there is no way to decide which certificate to use, you could look at using SNI or run dom2 on a different port.

Comment: I will look into SNI, hopefully I can get it to work that way.

Comment: It sounds like not all your clients support SNI. Which typical browsers are you using, on which platforms?

Comment: I actually already answered my own question. It wasnt a client issue I added 
NameVirtualHost *:443

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

to the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to the top of the config.

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:443

# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to host 2 named based SSL virtual host on the same IP address and port.
Apache will always use the first listed host which explains the error.

Link : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Comment: Crap...  It has multiple NIC's but I dont think adding a second internal Ip would do much good seeing as I can only forward 443 to one of them.

Comment: Actually, it is possible using SNI, as mentioned in the first link on that page you mention.